# Linux Headers not upgrading. It says "no space" when I have lots

Tags: upgrade, kernel, system-installation, inode

Problems with my linux-headers in a Ubuntu 13.10 upgrade.
It says:

```
E: / var/cache/apt/archives/linux-headers-3.11.0-15_3.11.0-15.25_all.deb: unable to create `/ usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-15/arch/powerpc / kernel / Makefile.dpkg-new '(while processing `./usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-15/arch/powerpc/kernel/Makefile'): Device with no free space 
E: / var/cache/apt/archives/linux-headers-3.11.0-15-generic_3.11.0-15.25_i386.deb: unable to create `/ usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-15-generic / include / config / dm / multipath / ql.h.dpkg-new '(while processing `./usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-15-generic/include/config/dm/multipath/ql.h '): Device with no free space
```

But I have a `/` with 18 Gb of space...

During the this happened:

```
  ( Reading database ... 244 922 files and directories currently installed . )
     Preparing to replace linux -image - 3.11.0 -15- generic 3.11.0-15.25 ( using ... / linux - image- 3.11.0 -15- generic_3.11.0 - 15.25_i386.deb ) ...
    Done .
    The unpack replacement linux - image- 3.11.0 -15- generic ...
    Examining / etc / kernel / postrm.d .
    run- parts: executing / etc / kernel / postrm.d / initramfs -tools 3.11.0 -15- generic / boot/vmlinuz-3.11.0-15-generic
    run- parts: executing / etc / kernel / postrm.d / zz - update- grub 3.11.0 -15- generic / boot/vmlinuz-3.11.0-15-generic
    Preparing to replace linux - headers -3.11.0-15 3.11.0-15.25 ( using ... / linux - headers - 3.11.0 - 15_3.11.0 - 15.25_all.deb ) ...
    The unpack replacement linux - headers - 3.11.0 -15 ...
    dpkg : error processar / var/cache/apt/archives/linux-headers-3.11.0-15_3.11.0-15.25_all.deb ( - unpack ) :
     No. managed to create ` / usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-15/arch/powerpc/kernel/Makefile.dpkg-new ' ( ` wile processing ./usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-15 / arch / powerpc / kernel / Makefile ' ) : No free space on device
    No apports paper written for MaxReports was reached
                                                                   dpkg - deb : error : the necklace was killed subprocess hair signal ( Channel interrupted )
    Preparing to replace linux - headers - 3.11.0 -15- generic 3.11.0-15.25 ( using ... / linux - headers - 3.11.0 -15- generic_3.11.0 - 15.25_i386.deb ) ...
    The unpack replacement linux - headers - 3.11.0 -15- generic ...
    dpkg : error processing / var/cache/apt/archives/linux-headers-3.11.0-15-generic_3.11.0-15.25_i386.deb ( - unpack ) :
     No. managed to create ` / usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-15-generic/include/config/dm/multipath/ql.h.dpkg-new ' ( enquanto processava ` . / usr / src / linux - headers -3.11.0-15-generic/include/config/dm/multipath/ql.h ' ) : No free space on device
    No apports paper written for MaxReports was reached
                                                                   dpkg - deb : error : the necklace was killed subprocess hair signal ( Channel interrupted )
    Preparing to replace linux -image - extra- 3.11.0 -15- generic 3.11.0-15.25 ( using ... / linux - image- extra- 3.11.0 -15- generic_3.11.0 - 15.25_i386.deb ) ...
    The unpack replacement linux - image- extra- 3.11.0 -15- generic ...
    Examining / etc / kernel / postrm.d .
    run- parts: executing / etc / kernel / postrm.d / initramfs -tools 3.11.0 -15- generic / boot/vmlinuz-3.11.0-15-generic
    run- parts: executing / etc / kernel / postrm.d / zz - update- grub 3.11.0 -15- generic / boot/vmlinuz-3.11.0-15-generic
    Foramen found errors while processing :
     / var/cache/apt/archives/linux-headers-3.11.0-15_3.11.0-15.25_all.deb
     / var/cache/apt/archives/linux-headers-3.11.0-15-generic_3.11.0-15.25_i386.deb
    W : He waited for dpkg - assert - multi- arch but wasn't wool - dpkgGo (10 : No. exist processes SON )
    E: Sub - process / usr / bin / dpkg returned an error code ( 1)
    The package failed to install . Trying to recover :
    Installing linux - image- 3.11.0 -15- generic ( 3.11.0-15.25 ) ...
    Running depmod .
    update- initramfs : deferring update ( hook will be called Later )
    Not updating initrd symbolic links since we are Being updated / reinstalled
    ( 3.11.0-15.25 WAS configured last , according to dpkg )
    Not updating image symbolic links since we are Being updated / reinstalled
    ( 3.11.0-15.25 WAS configured last , according to dpkg )
    Examining / etc / kernel / postinst.d .
    run- parts: executing / etc / kernel / postinst.d / apt self- removal - 3.11.0 -15- generic / boot/vmlinuz-3.11.0-15-generic
    run- parts: executing / etc / kernel / postinst.d / initramfs -tools 3.11.0 -15- generic / boot/vmlinuz-3.11.0-15-generic
    update- initramfs : Generating / boot/initrd.img-3.11.0-15-generic
    run- parts: executing / etc / kernel / postinst.d / pm - utils 3.11.0 -15- generic / boot/vmlinuz-3.11.0-15-generic
    run- parts: executing / etc / kernel / postinst.d / update- notifier 3.11.0 -15- generic / boot/vmlinuz-3.11.0-15-generic
    run- parts: executing / etc / kernel / postinst.d / zz - update- grub 3.11.0 -15- generic / boot/vmlinuz-3.11.0-15-generic
    Generating grub.cfg ...
    Found linux image : / boot/vmlinuz-3.11.0-17-generic
    Found initrd image : / boot/initrd.img-3.11.0-17-generic
    Found linux image : / boot/vmlinuz-3.11.0-15-generic
    Found initrd image : / boot/initrd.img-3.11.0-15-generic
    Found memtest86 + image : / memtest86 + . Bin
    done
    Installing linux - image- extra- 3.11.0 -15- generic ( 3.11.0-15.25 ) ...
    Running depmod .
    update- initramfs : deferring update ( hook will be called Later )
    Not updating initrd symbolic links since we are Being updated / reinstalled
    ( 3.11.0-15.25 WAS configured last , according to dpkg )
    Not updating image symbolic links since we are Being updated / reinstalled
    ( 3.11.0-15.25 WAS configured last , according to dpkg )
    Examining / etc / kernel / postinst.d .
    run- parts: executing / etc / kernel / postinst.d / apt self- removal - 3.11.0 -15- generic / boot/vmlinuz-3.11.0-15-generic
    run- parts: executing / etc / kernel / postinst.d / initramfs -tools 3.11.0 -15- generic / boot/vmlinuz-3.11.0-15-generic
    update- initramfs : Generating / boot/initrd.img-3.11.0-15-generic
    run- parts: executing / etc / kernel / postinst.d / pm - utils 3.11.0 -15- generic / boot/vmlinuz-3.11.0-15-generic
    run- parts: executing / etc / kernel / postinst.d / update- notifier 3.11.0 -15- generic / boot/vmlinuz-3.11.0-15-generic
    run- parts: executing / etc / kernel / postinst.d / zz - update- grub 3.11.0 -15- generic / boot/vmlinuz-3.11.0-15-generic
    Generating grub.cfg ...
    Found linux image : / boot/vmlinuz-3.11.0-17-generic
    Found initrd image : / boot/initrd.img-3.11.0-17-generic
    Found linux image : / boot/vmlinuz-3.11.0-15-generic
    Found initrd image : / boot/initrd.img-3.11.0-15-generic
    Found memtest86 + image : / memtest86 + . Bin
    done
```

I've uninstalled 3.11.0-15 and installed 3.11.0-17 with Synaptic. After this, I've done the folowing.

```
~$ df -h
File Sist.      Size  Ocup Free Use% Mouted in
/dev/sda6        19G  6,1G   12G  35% /
none            4,0K     0  4,0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev            3,9G  4,0K  3,9G   1% /dev
tmpfs           801M  1,2M  799M   1% /run
none            5,0M     0  5,0M   0% /run/lock
none            4,0G  216K  4,0G   1% /run/shm
none            100M   32K  100M   1% /run/user
/dev/sda1       270M   34M  218M  14% /boot
/dev/sda7       550G  497G   26G  96% /home
```

and

```
~$ df -hi
File Sist.     Inodes IOcup IFree UseI% Mounted in
/dev/sda6        1,2M  1,2M   27K   98% /
none             197K     2  197K    1% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev             193K   501  192K    1% /dev
tmpfs            197K   529  197K    1% /run
none             197K     3  197K    1% /run/lock
none             197K     8  197K    1% /run/shm
none             197K    23  197K    1% /run/user
/dev/sda1         72K   265   72K    1% /boot
/dev/sda7         35M  619K   35M    2% /home
```

After the kernel install, my Nautilus doesn't empty the trash, it crashes, and Dropbox, every time I boot my computer, it ask me for root previleges (ask for root password) and doesn't shows on tray.

Thanks!

Comment: It shows your `/usr` partition doesn't had enough space.So you have to increase it.

Comment: I have a `/` with 11Gb in a 18 Gb Space patition. More space?!
Ubuntu gives a limitation of space for `/usr` in my 18 Gb's?  
I uninstalled 3.11.0-15 with Synaptic and installed 3.11.0-17. Lets see what occours.  
Thank you both for the comments!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Device with no free space"

In ext filesystem this can mean that you don't have space in *bytes* but also you don't have space in *inodes*. Linux kernel have a lot of small files so you probably hit inode limit of your partition.

Type `df -h` to see size limit.

Type `df -hi` to see inode (file number) limit.

As far as i know, you can only set/increase inode limit when formating.
https://serverfault.com/questions/111857/linux-help-im-running-out-of-inodes

Answer (score 0):

I managed the problem moving some files to an external drive, deleting them from the PC and emptying the trash with the terminal.

```
sudo rm -rf ~/.local/share/Trash/*
```

The use reduced from 98% to 72%.

I don't know if it realy helps, but later I'll move all documents (`/home/username/all-of-this`) to an external drive and move it back again. Maybe my torrent downloads had break files into pieces.

Thanks to all!

Comment: note that your df shows that /home is a separate partition (with its own set of inodes) (but note that /root (root's home) is on your / partition).  If the problem recurs, you may want to use du --inodes / to narrow down where they're being used ... my experience was with /var/log/<something> having lots of zero or close to zero length files due to a bad log rotate script ... although I also don't see /tmp mounted which would be another possible place